# r- hist.default, 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, histogram

Just picking up R and I have the following question:

Say I have the following data.frame:

```
v1     v2     v3  
3      16     a  
44     457    d  
5      23     d  
34     122    c  
12     222    a
```

...and so on

I would like to create a histogram or barchart for this in R, but instead of having the x-axis be one of the numeric values, I would like a count by v3. (2 a, 1 c, 2 d...etc.)

If I do `hist(dataFrame$v3)`, I get the error that `'x 'must be numeric`.

1. Why can't it count the instances of each different string like it can for the other columns?
2. What would be the simplest code for this?

Answer (score 9):

OK. First of all, you should know exactly what a [histogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram) is. It is not a plot of counts. It is a visualization for **continuous** variables that estimates the underlying probability density function. So do not try to use `hist` on categorical data. (That's why `hist` tells you that the value you pass must be numeric.)

If you just want counts of discrete values, that's just a basic bar plot. You can calculate counts of values in R for discrete data using `table` and then plot that with the basic `barplot()` command.

```
barplot(table(dataFrame$v3))
```

If you want to require a minimum number of observations, try

```
tbl<-table(dataFrame$v3)
atleast <- function(i) {function(x) x>=i}
barplot(Filter(atleast(10), tbl))
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm a complete newbie to r. Now that I created this bar chart, I see that I have a lot of results in the hundreds and a few that just have a 1 or 2. Is there any way to exclude the data if it does not meet a minimum number of instances?

Comment: @user3594525 I've added a possible solution in my answer.